# Stability of SDE fBM

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, rough-paths

Consider an n-dimensional Ito process
$$
X_t^x = x + \int_0^t\, \alpha(s)ds + \int_0^t\,\beta(s)\,dB^H(s),
$$
where $1/3<H<1$ is the Hurst parameter for an $n$-dimensional fractional Brownian motion $(B^H(t))_{t\ge 0}$, and $\alpha,\beta$ are Lipschitz maps taking values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{S}(n)$.  Here, $\mathbb{S}(n)$ denotes the set of $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite matrices and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider its solution operator $x\mapsto X_t^x$.  Is this map (locally) Lipschitz in $x$ (for any fixed $t>0$)?  Also, is it clear that $X_t^x$ is Gaussian?

Comment: The solution is Lipschitz continuous with respect to the initial condition with unit Lipschitz constant, because the noise and drift are both additive.  Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are deterministic, $X_t^x$ is Gaussian, because the (Riemann-Stieltjes) integral of a deterministic function with respect to a fBM is Gaussian.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Do you have a reference for the fact that the integral against an fBM of a deterministic function is Gaussian; and more importantly, what is the distribution of $X_t^x$.  If $H=1/2$ I know how to compute this, but I have no idea in general.

Comment: Here is how I think about.  For simplicity, suppose $n=1$ and the integrand $\beta$ is a deterministic  $C^1$-function.  Let $I_t:=\int_0^t \beta(s) dB^H(s)$ and $R_{t,s} := E \{ B_t^H B_s^H \}$.  Then any reasonable definition of the fractional stochastic integral would satisfy $I_t = \beta(t) B_t^H - \int_0^t \beta’(s) B_s^H ds$, and since $B^H$ is continuous (hence Riemann integrable) and furthermore starts at zero, $I_t$ is Gaussian with mean zero and variance $\beta(t)^2 R_{t,t} - 2 \int_0^t R_{s,t} \beta(t) ds + \int_0^t \int_0^t \beta’(s) \beta’(r) R_{s,r} ds dr$.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments the Lip-continuity just follows from the linearity.

Similarly, for Gaussian, we can use that $\beta\in C^{1}$ and we can define the Young integral which is an approximation of sums of Gaussian eg. see ["Stochastic differential equations driven by
fractional Brownian motions"](https://fabricebaudoin.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/finland.pdf).

---

The things below are for worse regularity for $b$ and even of the form $b(t,X_{t})$.

For the range $(1/2,1]$ as explained in the comments Gaussian follows by the linearity and definition of Young integral.
["Stochastic differential equations driven by
fractional Brownian motions"](https://fabricebaudoin.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/finland.pdf)

[image]

See here for more general setting ["Continuous dependence of solutions of stochastic differential equations driven by standard and fractional Brownian motion on a parameter"](https://www.ams.org/journals/tpms/2011-83-00/S0094-9000-2012-00845-4/S0094-9000-2012-00845-4.pdf)

For $H=1/2$, you can similarly use the Ito integral formulation and its approximation by sums of Gaussians see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997061/the-ito-integral-is-gaussian).

For the $(1/3,1,2)$ or $(1/4,1/3)$, however one needs to use rough path lifts,
[image]

which might not be Gaussian anymore eg.

- "a course on rough paths" 10.3 Fractional Brownian motion and beyond
- original application ["Stochastic analysis, rough path analysis and fractional Brownian motions"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s004400100158.pdf)

Comment: If the integrand is deterministic and $C^1$, is the stochastic integral for $H<1/2$ really undefined?  One can actually take as definition: $I_t := \beta(t) B_t^H - \int_0^t \beta’_s B_s^H ds$, which is a centered Gaussian random variable.

Comment: thank you, I updated.